# "Everything But Arms" and migrants

Tags: european-union, economy, immigration

A common trope in Europe is that the European Union, by means of [exploitation](https://www.welt.de/print/wams/article140089396/Europa-hat-Afrika-ausgebeutet.html) and [stiff tariffs](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/feb/28/the-european-union-is-an-ongoing-disaster-for-africa), keeps the African economy down, thereby forcing economic migrants to leave home for Europe.

However, since 2001, the European Union has installed the [Everything But Arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_but_Arms) initiative, completely removing tariffs on anything for Least-Developed-Countries exporting to Europe.

Is there any evidence that this economic initiative has lead to a reduction of migrant numbers from these countries?

Comment: I suspect it would be pretty hard to tell in retrospect what caused a reduction (or increase) in migrants except for obvious things like war. One would need to have enough other explanatory variables in their model. Perhaps doable, but I'm not sure it was done. A quick search found papers analyzing the effect of EBA on exports, but not on more distant outcomes, like emigration.

Comment: The problem with questions in the format "has action X lead to a change in measure Y" in politics is that it is usually impossible to determine if Y was actually affected by X or rather by a completely unrelated parallel development Z. This question could be made a bit less speculative by taking a step back and asking how the European policy of free trade affected the economies of the least developed countries they import from. But that would also be extremely broad, because not all developing countries are alike.

Comment: The question asked for "refugees" in the title, but the body of the question is only talking about economic migrants. There is an important difference between these groups. A refugee is a person fleeing from political persecution while an economic migrant looks for a better quality of life. The difference is relevant because different laws and regulations apply to them in their destination country. EU countries are legally (and morally) obligated to accept refugees, but not to accept economic immigrants. I edited the title and removed the "refugees" tag.

Comment: @Philipp: The distinction is indeed important, but in practice, the EU accepts some economic migrants, at least temporarily https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/six-out-of-10-migrants-to-europe-come-for-economic-reasons-and-are-not-refugees-eu-vice-president-a6836306.html

Comment: @Fizz While it is true that some economic migrants *claim* to be refugees in order to circumvent the usual application process does not mean they *are* refugees. It also doesn't mean that every refugee is an economic migrant or that every economic migrant came to Europe by exploiting the asylum system. Trying to conflate all these groups into one is a common rhethoric tactic of the racists in Europe to discriminate all foreigners based on origin alone. So it is important to insist on the differences.

Comment: @Philipp: I never they are the same thing. But consider the practicality of having to come to a decision whether someone is a legitimate refugee or economic migrant. Some EU states prefer to pay these people some money (ot leave) rather than going through the lengthy decision process: https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-worried-migrants-will-shop-around-for-best-voluntary-return-deal-payment/ So whether the EU accepts them or not... just getting that money might still be an incentive for them to emigrate/try.

Comment: @Philipp: I tried to keep the question unbiased. You have added this bias: "common rhethoric tactic of the racists". Do you deny that many economic migrants are using the refugee ticket to enter Europe because it is the simplest way? The conflation of these two different terms is exactly what these "racist" parties are complaining about!

Comment: From the first link: "The wave of refugees is not temporary, but will take months, years and years to come [...] More than 1.1 billion people live in Africa, half of whom are younger than 25, and more than 50 percent of them is without work, we have to show perspectives for this generation, " (Google Translate) The German Secretary of Development (surely not a racist in your eyes?) himself implies these refugees (his words) come for economic reasons.

Comment: @Cliff As I already explained, there are 3 groups of people moving to Europe: 1. genuine refugees fleeing from persecution, 2. economic immigrants fraudulently claiming to be refugees, 3. economic immigrants who go through the regular immigration process. People tend to make justified complaints about group 2, but then imply that the groups 1 and 3 do not exist which means all immigration needs to be opposed. But they do. That's why it is important to differentiate. The question is about economy, so it is by definition only about groups 2 and 3 (economic immigrants).

Comment: This happens on both sides: others argue that group 2 does not exist (and call racist those who disagree). The conflation of terms happens on all sides of the political spectrum. In the end, it boils down to semantics. I'm fine with changing the word "refugee" to "migrant". However, your focus on and use of the term "racists" makes you appear biased. This should not be a platform for political activism, as a moderator once said.

Answer (score 4):

According to [one paper](https://econpapers.repec.org/paper/zbwgdec10/42.htm) EBA (unlike aid) probably had a *negative* effect on trade

> The main results show a negative effect of the EBA regime on exports. Otherwise, the combined effect of the EBA and aid on exports is positive, supporting an EU development strategy that includes both sorts of assistance, aid and trade preferences.

[Another paper](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-5965.2009.02004.x) says

> effects [of EBA] in terms of trade flows have been modest

And a [3rd paper](https://ideas.repec.org/p/sus/susewp/2711.html)...

> Overall the results suggest preferences have a very small impact on trade, and negligible or even negative when we consider the scope for trade diversification. Therefore, it appears that the GSP system has provided a small effect on increasing exports at the intensive margin, but no effect on export diversification.

I couldn't find any papers estimating the effect of EBA on emigration... but assuming the papers quoted above are correct, EBA itself couldn't have been good for diminishing economic migration, or the effect was fairly negligible.